# Wait for dynamic child images to finish loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a situation like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $("body").append("<div id='container'></div>");
    var i=1;
    for ( i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
            $("#container").append("<img src='img"+i+".jpg'></img>");
    }
});
```

Which will load 10 random images which can be different sizes (img1.jpg...jp10.jpg).  Now let's say I need some property from these images.  For example, the total height combined of the 10 loaded images.  This requires all the images to be loaded before we can use `.height()`.

Now the question:

How can I wait until all images are loaded before I start the calculation?  Or even more general, how can I wait until all images in some given container are loaded before I execute a function?

With 1 image, I can use `.load()` and have a callback function.  But with multiple images, does not seem very easy.  One solution would be to add a `.load()` to every image that adds to a counter, and once that counter reaches a certain value, then execute the function.  Seems a tiny bit hacky (but not TOO hacky).  Just wanted to get some opinions on this matter.

Comment: I would go with your hack because sounds like either way you have to keep a count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create those images with jQuery aswell and attach an `onload`-eventhandler for those either. Also you could combine that with jQuery's Deferred objects to link things together. That might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<div id='container'></div>");
    var i      = 1,
        images = [ ],
        $img   = null;

    for ( i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
        $img = $('<img>', {
            load: function() {
                images.push( $.Deferred(function( promise ) {
                    promise.resolve();
                }).promise() );
            }
        }).appendTo( '#container' );

        $img.attr('src', 'img' + i + '.jpg');
    }

    $.when.apply( null, images ).done( function() {
        // all images were loaded here, do whatever you want.
    });
});
```

In that constelation, the `done` handler will only fire if all images could get loaded successfully. If you want to know if at least one image failed loading, you could also bind an `error` event handler and `reject()` a promise. Finally use `.then( success, failure )` instead of `.done()`.

By the way, I guess it makes more sense to put that code into the `DOMContentLoaded` (jQuery's `.ready()`).

Comment: I wonder if you can *necessarily* expect jQuery to hook up the `load` handler before setting the `src` attribute when you supply them at the same time like that? Because if not, you have a race condition: If jQuery sets the `src` before setting `load`, and the image is in cache, the browser may fire the `load` event immediately, before jQuery sets up the `load` handler. (JavaScript is single-threaded; the browser is not. The browser can *fire* the event at any time, the handlers for it would queue -- but not if they haven't been set yet.) To be sure, I'd hook `load` first, explicitly.

Comment: @TJCrowder: what you mean by "hook it first explicitly" ? Within the object literal ? There is guaranted order in object literals as you of course know, so that would not make any difference. But I guess I get you wrong here.

Comment: @ jAndy: No, the properties in a literal are completely unordered. I would leave `src` out of the literal entirely, then go back and set it after the `img` element has been created. It's the only way to be sure. I should say that I'm not speaking hypothetically; I've proven with experimentation in the past (with raw JavaScript) that if you set `src` on one line and hook `load` on *the very next line*, you *can* miss the event on in some browsers if the image is in cache. You never miss the event if you hook it *first*, then set `src`.

Comment: @TJCrowder: yes I know about that problematic. But I really trusted in the jQuery core coders to set the `src` property before any handlers on element creation. However I didn't look that up so far, but it might be interesting to find out.

Comment: @ jAndy: *" I really trusted in the jQuery core coders to set the src property before any handlers on element creation"* It's the other way around. You have to hook up the handlers first, *then* set `src`. Just looked at the jQuery source, and I see nothing there guaranteeing it hooks the handler first. I could have missed it, but more to the point, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) doesn't guarantee it. If it ain't in the docs, don't rely on it. Setting `src` afterward doesn't cost anything, and saves a nasty intermittent bug.

Comment: @ jAndy: Here's what I'm talking about: http://pastie.org/2256345 Didn't edit it directly into your answer because it seems too intrusive. You also want to avoid looking up `#container` every time, and avoid all of it if `#container` doesn't exist on the page; I've included those in that link as well. (FYI, the browsers in which I've seen it. I know I've seen it in IE6, pretty sure in IE7, wouldn't be at all surprised if it was in later versions as well, and in other browsers.) Have to run, best,

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understand this code.  What does the last line mean?  And the `promise()` stuff?

Comment: @vinceh: In this case, it's a really complicated way to have a counter.

Comment: If it's a complicated way of having a counter, what are the benefits of this implementation over just a simple counter?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading the images with JS, the only way for you to know when they're all loaded is to monitor each and every one with a load event handler.  So, given that, I'd say your counter idea sounds like the simplest way to go.

If you were loading the images in the page source, you could use the page's onload handler because that waits for all images to be done loading.

The only other simple possibility I can think of is to preload the images by putting them in the actual page as  image tags.  They can be hidden if you don't want them to display in that location.  Then, they will be loaded by the browser before the page onload handler is executed and they will be ready for you to examine their sizes and then append new image tags (using the same URL's elsewhere in the page).  Since the browser will have already loaded them, the new tags will be loaded from cache so there's no real speed issue.